# JQUERY appended element doesn't toggle itself after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

i'm appending some forms on click event. each form has it's own submit button that sends request to PHP file through ajax. after a succeed request i want to remove the button that was pressed.

> JQUERY VERSION: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

```
<button id="search-button" class="sbtn"> Create Buttons </button>

<div class="rs">
</div>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

      $(".sbtn").click(function(){
        var results = '<br><form><input  name="submit" id="mehide" type="submit" class="category_button_short" value="SEND TO PHP"/></form><br><form><input  name="submit" id="mehide" type="submit" class="category_button_short" value="SEND TO PHP"/></form><br><form><input  name="submit" id="mehide" type="submit" class="category_button_short" value="SEND TO PHP"/></form>';
        $('.rs').append(results);
      });

      $(document).on('click', ".category_button_short", function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/echo/html/',
          data: {
            html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>",
          },
          success: function(data)
          {
            alert(data);
            $(this.form).find('.category_button_short').hide();// doesn't work
            //here i want to vanish 'SEND TO PHP' which one is pressed.
            //$(this).hide();     
          }
        });

      return false;
      });
});
```

But pressed button doesn't vanish. how to target BUTTON inside it's parent form ?

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cvwevgx1/)

Comment: `$(this).find('form').find('.category_button_short').hide();`

Comment: @Amin tested on jsfiddle but didn't work!

Comment: right, 'cause `this` isn't referring to the element

Comment: your form object is overwrite by ajax object. So store your form object in another variable. check this fiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/cvwevgx1/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside ajax function points to xhr options object and not the current element.

Pass `context : this` as an option to ajax.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvwevgx1/4/)

Also, by the below are you trying to hide the currently clicked element? If so just `$(this).hide()` would work.

`$(this.form).find('.category_button_short').hide();`